# Terraform - creating multiple buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

Creating a bucket is pretty simple.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "henrys_bucket" {
  bucket                  = "${var.s3_bucket_name}"
  acl                     = "private"
  force_destroy           = "true"
}
```

Initially I thought I could create a list for the `s3_bucket_name` variable but I get an error:

```
Error: bucket must be a single value, not a list
```

-

```
variable "s3_bucket_name" {
  type = "list"
  default  = ["prod_bucket", "stage-bucket", "qa_bucket"]
}
```

How can I create multiple buckets without duplicating code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`count`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#using-variables-with-count) & [`element`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#element-list-index-) like so:

```
variable "s3_bucket_name" {
  type    = "list"
  default = ["prod_bucket", "stage-bucket", "qa_bucket"]
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "henrys_bucket" {
  count         = "${length(var.s3_bucket_name)}"
  bucket        = "${element(var.s3_bucket_name, count.index)}"
  acl           = "private"
  force_destroy = "true"
}
```

Edit: as suggested by @ydaetskcoR you can use the `list[index]` pattern rather than element.

```
variable "s3_bucket_name" {
  type    = "list"
  default = ["prod_bucket", "stage-bucket", "qa_bucket"]
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "henrys_bucket" {
  count         = "${length(var.s3_bucket_name)}"
  bucket        = "${var.s3_bucket_name[count.index]}"
  acl           = "private"
  force_destroy = "true"
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `list[index]` syntax over `element(list, index)` syntax unless you really need to be able to loop back over the list (such as spreading instances over subnets or other things where you have unequal list lengths).

Comment: @ydaetskcoR can you provide an example.

Comment: Good point. I've updated my answer to show the new `list[index]` syntax

Comment: @ConorMongey @ydaetskcoR  how would I go about attaching a policy to a s3 bucket. I'm getting an error `Resource 'aws_iam_policy.nexus_user_policy' not found for variable 'aws_iam_policy.nexus_user_policy.arn'`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53770191/terraform-attach-policy-to-s3-bucket

Comment: When I do this I get `Error: Duplicate provider configuration` does this mean I need a unique provider for each bucket?