# Multi S3 bucket Definition with versioning limitations

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, bucket

I was reading this post: [Terraform - creating multiple buckets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53764505/terraform-creating-multiple-buckets/71304282#71304282)

and was wondering how could I have added a filter to enable bucket versioning on one of the buckets and disable versioning on the rest of the buckets using terraform conditionals or anything that would allow it to work?
I was trying something like this but it is not working

```
variable "s3_bucket_name" {
  type    = "list"
  default = ["prod_bucket", "stage-bucket", "qa_bucket"]
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "henrys_bucket" {
  count         = "${length(var.s3_bucket_name)}"
  bucket        = "${var.s3_bucket_name[count.index]}"
  acl           = "private"
  force_destroy = "true"
  var.s3_bucket_name[count.index] != "target-bucket-name" versioning { enabled = true } : versioning { enabled = false }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list of objects instead of just list of bucket names. The object can contain bucket name, and versioning_enabled flag. Then use the bucket-name and  versioning_enabled.

Something like:

```
bucket        = var.s3_buckets[count.index].bucket_name
```

And for versioning, add dynamic block based on var.s3_buckets[count.index].versioning_enabled like below:

```
dynamic "versioning" {
  for_each = var.s3_buckets[count.index].versioning_enabled== true ? [1] : []
  content {
    enabled = true
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you that did it. I very much appreciate your help.